# Is Eclipse(IDE) directory dependant

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

I wanted to find out if Eclipse is directory dependent. In other words, will the location that your package is stored on affect whether or not you will be able to run a program.

I am asking this because I am a university student and have to upload my work remotely, and if our projects do not run on the campus computers our work wont be marked

If Eclipse is directory dependent, do you have any other recommendations in terms of IDEs or text editors that will be able to save my work in a .java format

Answer (score 0):

Everything in an Eclipse workspace uses paths which are relative to the workspace root so you should be able to move the whole workspace to another location without problem.